# how to solve svg path stoke width different thickness

Tags: css, svg, frontend

I have a square hexagonal svg image, and i set stroke-width 4px for it.
But the stroke thickness is not consistent, the vertical lines are thinner and the slanted lines are thicker.

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIrNM.png)

```html
<svg width="173" height="199" viewBox="0 0 173 199" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path stroke='#5088ff' stroke-width="4px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-linecap="square" d="M86.5 0L173 50V150L86.5 199L0 150V50L86.5 0Z"/>
</svg>
```

I have searched and tried `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`, it does't work.

Comment: Your strokes overlap outside of the svg. You can quick-solve that by [changing your <svg> `overflow` property](https://jsfiddle.net/ruwkb7n8/), but the best would be to author your shape so that it fits correctly in the intended viewport, or you could also change the `viewBox`.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you so much! I tried to set a bigger width to the svg tag, it works, the stroke looks nice. can i ask a question more, how can you find it in such short time? I have tried different way for 2-3 hours, and i didn't find the width is wrong.

Comment: Experience I guess.

Comment: maybe i should read some ducoment about viewBox and stroke-width, i am not sure the stroke is in the viewBox or out the viewBox. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the stroke is not outside the viewBox. A stroke will be painted equal inside and outside the path outline.

Here I moved the path using transform/translate and make the width and the height of the viewBox larger.

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 177 203" fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path stroke='#5088ff' transform="translate(2 2)" stroke-width="4"
    vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-linecap="square"
    d="M 86.5 0 L 173 50 V 150 L 86.5 199 L 0 150 V 50 L 86.5 0 Z"/>
</svg>
```